# jquery toggle works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

my intention is to write code that toggles back and forth when any of the two buttons are clicked , its simple code but not working as expected:

```
$('#pup_container').load('plst_main_f/login_form.php').hide();
$('#login_activate').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#pup_container').fadeIn(950);
});

$('#button_img').click(function () {
    $('#login_wrapper_background').slideToggle(755);
});
```

works fine the first time around, but isn't TOGGLING like its supposed to, the toggle happens once and  its probably because they are triggered with different buttons but i'm not quite sure, please help

code here is part of the ready function.

Comment: which toggle is working the `login_activate` one?

Comment: also the jQuery version used

Comment: Are the `#login_activate` and/or `#button_img` elements contained within the html loaded in the `.load()` statement?

Comment: only the `#button_img` is in the .load() statement.

Comment: then you need to bind that handler in the load callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the button_img is loaded dynamically, you need to bind the handler after the element is loaded dynamically

```
$('#pup_container').load('plst_main_f/login_form.php', function () {
    $('#button_img').click(function () {
        $('#login_wrapper_background').slideToggle(755);
    });
}).hide();
$('#login_activate').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login_wrapper_background').toggle(950, function () {});
});
```

Or use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)